# Is there a way to add horizonal scrolling to vuetify calendar when using categories?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, calendar, vuetify.js

I am looking for a way to add horizontal scrolling when using categories so the calendar doesn't get squished when more categories are added. Is there a way that I can scroll horizontally within the v-calendar? I've tried using vue-virtual-scrollbar but it ended up scrolling the entire calendar including the dates and the times.

The end goal would be to keep the Category names on a vertical scroll and to keep the time of day on the horizontal scroll.

https://codepen.io/kodyvs/pen/gOMeOwB --> this is an example of what's happening

```js
import * as vueCustomScrollbar from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/vue-custom-scrollbar@1.4.0";
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data: () => ({
      settings: {
      suppressScrollY: false,
      suppressScrollX: false,
      wheelPropagation: false,
    },
      focus: '',
      events: [],
      colors: ['blue', 'indigo', 'deep-purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'orange', 'grey darken-1'],
      names: ['Meeting', 'Holiday', 'PTO', 'Travel', 'Event', 'Birthday', 'Conference', 'Party'],
      categories: ['John Smith', 'Tori Walker','John Smith1', 'Tori Walker1','John Smith2', 'Tori Walker2', 'John Smith3', 'Tori Walker3'],
    }),
    mounted () {
      this.$refs.calendar.checkChange()
    },
    methods: {
      getEventColor (event) {
        return event.color
      },
      setToday () {
        this.focus = ''
      },
      prev () {
        this.$refs.calendar.prev()
      },
      next () {
        this.$refs.calendar.next()
      },
      fetchEvents ({ start, end }) {
        const events = []

        const min = new Date(`${start.date}T00:00:00`)
        const max = new Date(`${end.date}T23:59:59`)
        const days = (max.getTime() - min.getTime()) / 86400000
        const eventCount = this.rnd(days, days + 20)

        for (let i = 0; i < eventCount; i++) {
          const allDay = this.rnd(0, 3) === 0
          const firstTimestamp = this.rnd(min.getTime(), max.getTime())
          const first = new Date(firstTimestamp - (firstTimestamp % 900000))
          const secondTimestamp = this.rnd(2, allDay ? 288 : 8) * 900000
          const second = new Date(first.getTime() + secondTimestamp)

          events.push({
            name: this.names[this.rnd(0, this.names.length - 1)],
            start: first,
            end: second,
            color: this.colors[this.rnd(0, this.colors.length - 1)],
            timed: !allDay,
            category: this.categories[this.rnd(0, this.categories.length - 1)],
          })
        }

        this.events = events
      },
      rnd (a, b) {
        return Math.floor((b - a + 1) * Math.random()) + a
      },
    },
})
```

```css
.scroll-area {
  position: auto;
  margin: auto;
  height: 700px;
  width: 2100px;
}
::v-deep v-calendar-category__column-header {
  min-width: 1000px;
}
::v-deep .v-calendar-daily_head-weekday,
::v-deep .v-calendar-daily_head-day-label {
  display: none;
}
::v-deep .v-select__selections {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
                  <v-row class="fill-height">
    <v-col>
      <v-sheet height="64">
        <v-toolbar
          flat
        >
          <v-btn
            outlined
            class="mr-4"
            color="grey darken-2"
            @click="setToday"
          >
            Today
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn
            fab
            text
            small
            color="grey darken-2"
            @click="prev"
          >
            <v-icon small>
              mdi-chevron-left
            </v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn
            fab
            text
            small
            color="grey darken-2"
            @click="next"
          >
            <v-icon small>
              mdi-chevron-right
            </v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-toolbar-title v-if="$refs.calendar">
            {{ $refs.calendar.title }}
          </v-toolbar-title>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        </v-toolbar>
      </v-sheet>
      <vue-custom-scrollbar class="scroll-area" :settings="settings">
      <v-sheet height="600" width="2100px">
        <v-calendar
          ref="calendar"
          v-model="focus"
          color="primary"
          type="category"
          category-show-all
          :categories="categories"
          :events="events"
          :event-color="getEventColor"
          @change="fetchEvents"
        ></v-calendar>
      </v-sheet>
        </vue-custome-scrollbar>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Just checking if you've solved this issue?